# C# Exchange web service - send and immediately retrieve sent message

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, exchange-server

The system I'm working has a requirement where the `MimeContent` of a just-sent email is stored in a local database. My understanding of how Exchange works is that it will create the `MimeContent` on the server and I cannot access it unless I query the service for that just-sent message.

So, the steps I take are:

-- Send the email and get it's `Id`

```
message.SendAndSaveCopy();
return message.Id.UniqueId;
```

-- Use the new id to get the just-sent `EmailMessage`

```
ExchangeService exchangeService = ExchangeService;

var properties = new List<PropertyDefinitionBase>
{
    ItemSchema.MimeContent
};

EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchangeService, new ItemId(messageId), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, properties));
```

When this code runs without interruption, it works. The `Id` returned is still valid (message is in the outbox folder perhaps) and I get the result. However, if I slow it down for even a second, the Id is no longer valid (I guess it's now moved into the sent folder).

I cannot leave it like this as there is no guarantee I will get back to the server in time to retrieve the message with that `Id`.

If there is a solution that involves me not having to query the service for the message again, that'd be swell. However, if not, is there a way I can use the `Id` and `ChangeKey` to get the just-sent email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually answered my own question. I did this by adding a custom property onto each email that I control. I then use that same value to search for the email. I had some issues with the email moving between folders inbetween the queries but it's sorted now.

- Define this somewhere, I have it within my EmailProvider class:

  ```
  private readonly PropertyDefinitionBase _TempEmailId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "TempEmailId", MapiPropertyType.String);
  ```
- Then add it just before you send the email:

  ```
  string messageId = null;
  if (getTempId)
  {
      messageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      message.SetExtendedProperty((ExtendedPropertyDefinition) _TempEmailId, messageId);
  }

  message.SendAndSaveCopy();
  return messageId;
  ```
- Finally, use the `messageId` to get the `MimeContent` (or any other properties you desire):

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Get the mime content for an email just sent
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="messageId"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public byte[] GetJustSentMimeContent(string messageId)
  {
      ExchangeService exchangeService = ExchangeService;

      // Use the following search filter to get mail with TempEmailId set to what we just got
      var searchCriteria = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(_TempEmailId, messageId);

      var itemView = new ItemView(1) {PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly)};

      byte[] GetMimeContent(WellKnownFolderName folder)
      {
          var items = exchangeService.FindItems(folder, searchCriteria, itemView);

          if (items.TotalCount > 0)
          {
              // if it's still in there, try and load the properties for it
              exchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems(items,
                  new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
                      ItemSchema.MimeContent));

              var emailMessage = (EmailMessage) items.First();

              // if the content has been loaded, return it
              if (emailMessage.MimeContent != null)
                  return emailMessage.MimeContent.Content;
          }

          return null;
      }

      // check the drafts folder to see if it's still in there
      var mimeContent = GetMimeContent(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts);

      if (mimeContent != null)
          return mimeContent;

      // if at this point, either: 
      // - email was moved to SentItems before the first search was done
      // - or email was found in Drafts but then moved to SentItems but before the MimeContent could be loaded. Need to restart the process and find the email in SentItems instead

      // should be in here (sentItems) now, try and load the properties for it
      return GetMimeContent(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems);
  }
  ```